# MVC Drop Down List issue : There is no Viewdata item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Contoller:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetAssiginee()
    {        
        var AssigineeList = await this.handsService.GetTeamTask();
        var content = from p in AssigineeList.Data

        orderby p.claimid
        select new { p.claimid, p.Assiginee};

        var x = content.ToList().Select(c => new List<SelectListItem>
         {
        new SelectListItem { Text = c.claimid, Value = c.Assiginee},

        }).ToList();
         ViewBag.FirstName = x;

         return View();
         }
```

Model :

```
public class ClaimDetails
{
    public int Assigineeid { get; set; }
public List<ClaimDetails> AssigineeList { get; set; }
    public int  ID { get; set; }
    public string claimid { get; set; }
    public string contactID { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    public string ForensicDueDate { get; set; }
    public string ForensicDueTime { get; set; }
    public string PatientFirstName { get; set; }
    public string PatientLastName { get; set; }
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public string ProviderName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PreScreen { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public string Edit { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public string Assiginee
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.FirstName ?? string.Empty, this.LastName ?? string.Empty).Trim();
        }
        set
        {
        }
    }
     public string Patient
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.PatientFirstName ?? string.Empty, this.PatientLastName ?? string.Empty).Trim();
        }
    }
}
}
```

View DropDown List:

I try for those DropDownList ,but showing Error Message

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FirstName,
new SelectList(ViewBag.FirstName as IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "claimid", "FirstName"),
"Select Assiginee",
new { @style = "width: 180px;height:30px;", id = "ddlAssiginee", @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownList("dropdownCountry", new SelectList(string.Empty, "claimid", "FirstName"), "Select Assiginee", new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:250px;" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID, ViewBag.FirstName as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)

@Html.DropDownList("ddldepartmentlist", ViewBag.FirstName as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

JavsScript Function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/TeamTaskScreen/GetAssiginee",

            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#ddldepartmentlist').append('<option value="' + value.claimid + '">' + value.FirstName + '</option>');
                    debugger;
                });
            }
        });    
    });

</script>
```

values are coming in Contoller but I Got Error Message in DropDownList

There is no Viewdata item of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` that has the key

Please help any one.

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag works when you set it in a GET action and try to access it in the view returned by that action method. But in your code, you are making an ajax call to get the data for the dropdown. Your ajax call's success method is expecting an array of items each with `claimId` and `FirstName`, but currently you server method is trying to return a view result!

Your view is expecting the a ViewBag item with name `FirstName` which has the collection of SelectListItems to render the SELECT element options. That means you need to set this ViewBag item in the GET Action method which returns this view, not in some other action method called by an ajax call.

So update your GET action to set this data.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   // your existing code to load content collection here
   var x = content.Select(c => new List<SelectListItem>
                                            {
                                               Text = c.claimid,
                                               Value = c.Assiginee},    
                                            }).ToList();
   ViewBag.FirstName = x;
   return View();
}
```

Another option is to simply use the Ajax method. For this, you may return the data in JSON format from your `GetAssiginee` method.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAssiginee()
{
    var AssigineeList = await this.handsService.GetTeamTask();
    var content = from p in AssigineeList.Data
    orderby p.claimid
    select new { p.claimid, p.Assiginee};

    var x = content.Select(c => new  claimid= c.claimid,
                                     FirstName= c.Assiginee}).ToList();       
    return Json(x,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The above code will return a json array like below

```
[
  { "claimid":"1","FirstName":"Some Name"},
  { "claimid":"2","FirstName":"Some Other Name"}    
]
```

and your current js code will be able to loop through the array and append options to the select element.

Now since you are populating the data via ajax, no need to use VieBag. Simple replace

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddldepartmentlist", ViewBag.FirstName as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
```

with

```
<SELECT name="ddldepartmentlist"></SELECT>
```